# How to store hindi data in data base using soap or rest service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, oracle-maf

I have created a table in oracle database which support utf-8(Hindi) format. Now i want to store hindi data in oracle database with the help of Soap service.
I am using Jdeveloper IDE 
And here what i am trying to do

```
 @WebMethod
 public String insertRecord(@WebParam(name="ASSEMBLY") String assembly, 
                             @WebParam(name="NAME")  String name, 
                              @WebParam(name="SURNAME") String surname, 
                              @WebParam(name="GENDER") String gender,
                             @WebParam(name="AGE")  int age,
                               @WebParam(name="DATEOFBIRTH") java.sql.Date dob,
                             @WebParam(name="PLACEOFBIRTH")  String pob,
                             @WebParam(name="HNO")  String hno,
                             @WebParam(name="STREET")  String street,
                             @WebParam(name="CITY")  String city,
                               @WebParam(name="POSTOFFICE") String po,
                               @WebParam(name="TEHSIL") String tehsil,
                               @WebParam(name="PINCODE")int pc, 
                               @WebParam(name="DISTRICT")String district,
                               @WebParam(name="FAMILYNAME")String fn, 
                               @WebParam(name="FAMRELATION")String fr, 
                               @WebParam(name="PARTNO")String part, 
                               @WebParam(name="SERIALNO")String serial, 
                               @WebParam(name="IDNO")String idno,
                               @WebParam(name="PHOTO")Blob photo){
        String result=null;
        try{
           con=dbc.getConnection();
            pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1,assembly);
            pst.setString(2, name);
            pst.setString(3,surname);
            pst.setString(4,gender);
            pst.setInt(5, age);
            pst.setDate(6, dob);
            pst.setString(7, pob);
            pst.setString(8, hno);
            pst.setString(9, street);
            pst.setString(10, city);
            pst.setString(11, po);
            pst.setString(12, tehsil);
            pst.setInt(13,pc);
            pst.setString(14, district);
            pst.setString(15, fn);
            pst.setString(16, fr);
            pst.setString(17, part);
            pst.setString(18, serial);
            pst.setString(19, idno);
            pst.setBlob(20,photo);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            result="Record Inserted";
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
            try{
                dbc.closeConnection();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        return result;
    }
```

Now when i test this web service and provide some input. Soap covert them into ????? and store this data in my oracle database

In my oracle data base datatype i have used in **nvarchar2(100)**

please help me.....

Thanks & Regard
Ujjawal Srivastava

Answer (score 0):

Find the Solution of My Problem.

I have set the Character set of my database as AL32UTF8.
Datatype is set to nvarchar(size)

finally right click on ViewController -> Project Properties-> Compiler

set Character Encoding as UTF-8